# Show Lao language in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have tried for hours but nothing work

This is my code

```
CREATE TABLE Sample(
     ID varchar(10),
     name varchar(17),
     PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)

INSERT INTO Sample 
VALUES('113','ພາ​ສາ​ລາວ')

SELECT * 
FROM Sample
```

Result:

```
111,????????
```

It should show 113 ພາ​ສາ​ລາວ on the table

Any solution will greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the unicode-enabled `NVARCHAR` data type when using these sorts of characters. When inputting these characters, you need to signify it's an NVARCHAR string by prefacing the literal with the `N` character.

Example:

```
declare @x varchar(max) = 'າ​ສາ​ລາ'
declare @y nvarchar(max) = N'າ​ສາ​ລາ'

select @x, @y
```

Returns:

```
???????  , າ​ສາ​ລາ
```

---

So a full example from your code would be:

```
CREATE TABLE Sample(
     ID varchar(10),
     name nvarchar(17),
     PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)

INSERT INTO Sample 
VALUES('113',N'ພາ​ສາ​ລາວ')

SELECT * 
FROM Sample
```

Comment: i'm quite new in ssms so can you please give the full code

Comment: thank you so much it is really helpful for me, without your help i would have a headache for a long time

Comment: oh sure, this is the first time for me in Stack over flow so, i don't know its features hope i tick the right place